# How can i increase the height of a box (border) relativaly to the amount of text in it?

Tags: html, css

I want to increase/decrease the height of the border in response of the amout of text inside it

This is my HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "box">
    <p>1st element</p>
    <p>second element</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the actual css :

```
.box{
  border : solid 1px grey;
  width: 150px;
  height: 55px;
  font-size: small;
  text-align: center;
}
```

fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/4dq6usgc/4/

Comment: min-height isntead of height

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to declare the height at all? If you remove it, the container will automatically adjust its height to match your content.

Comment: @oaklandrichie You're right. I've adjusted by answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `height:auto` or `height:fit-content`

**Height: Auto**

Take not that removing the height will automatically set the height to `auto`

```css
.box{
  border : solid 1px grey;
  width: 150px;
  height:auto;
  font-size: small;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "box">
    <p>1st element</p>
    <p>second element</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Height: Fit-Content**

```css
.box{
  border : solid 1px grey;
  width: 150px;
  height: fit-content;
  font-size: small;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "box">
    <p>1st element</p>
    <p>second element</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

They have the same effect.